# Independent science-fiction movie, spaceship crew dies of oxygen deprivation, some survivors befriend an alien who learns our language

Tags: story-identification, movie, aliens

The movie starts out with two astronauts playing catch with an egg-shaped rock on the moon. Then they take the object onto their spaceship, and the crew ends up dying from lack of oxygen.

The spaceship ends up at a space station, which blows up, a few of the space station personnel escape onto the same spaceship, which has the undiscovered alien on it, some of the personnel get killed, the survivors end up becoming close friends with the alien, who learns our language.

Comment: How do you know it was an independent film? And when did you watch it? Was it in English? CG? Cartoon? Live Action? I highly advise going to https://scifi.stackexchange.com/tags/story-identification/info and answering as many of the questions as you can by editing your answer.

Comment: Someone answered, the movie is called "Start Crystal' and i guess it is not an Indie, TY

Answer (score 6):

["Star Crystal"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Star_Crystal) (1986)?

It was low-budget, which I'm assuming is why you thought it was an independent film. It has the plot points you described, including an alien who kills almost everyone on board but was only doing so to defend itself. It ends up befriending the two survivors at the end.

Comment: You can accept the answer, Jake, by clicking on the checkmark by the voting buttons.